# Docxtpl: Add heading level to text

Tags: python, cpu-word, doc, docxtpl

How can I add a heading level to text with docxtpl?

Can I do something like this: ?

```
rt = RichText()
rt.add('Headername', level=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is just to adjust the font size of your `{{ Headername }}` expression in the template document:

[image: screenshot of template]